# Is there an Artifactory exporter/Datasource to Grafana, to create an Dashboard with information about artifactory folders (size files/subfolders etc)

Tags: directory, grafana, artifactory, dashboard, exporter

We aim to implement a dashboard for Artifactory in Grafana to showcase detailed information about folders, going beyond the current focus on repositories. we are using this Exporter:
https://github.com/peimanja/artifactory_exporter

Presently, the Artifactory exporter provides information about the quantity of folders in a repository. We need also insights about the size of the folder, and also recursively its subfolders.

we are open about the formatting, it could be graphical, or even text based.

Something like this

http://filepony.de/screenshot/spacesniffer2.png
https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/scr

The primary use case is to enhance the visibility of folder-level details in the Grafana dashboard. This feature would allow users to gain insights into the size of data within specific folders. The goal is to provide a more comprehensive view of Artifactory metrics beyond repository-level metrics. We are having gigantic amounts of artefacts, so information on repository level is not enough anymore.

Eventually, we gonna need to write our own DataSource for Grafana for that. But before extending an existing exporter, i wanted to ask a question here, maybe somebody has already solved this issue in the past :) ?

we checked the currently available exporter metrix.

Then we checked what graphical end solutions would be acceptable for us.

Now we have to decide which path do we want to go.

Idea right now is to find a grafana dashboard that is capable of displaying file system, and then extend the Artifactory exporter to export the needed metrics, so that it can be used for the dashboard.

Comment: Hi Vilius, your question has a problem: you are mixing exporter part of problem and visualization. If your exporter doesn't expose metrics of folder sizes (and AFAICT it doesn't), no dashboard will help you. So you need to focus on obtaining data that you want to visualize. [But be cautious: questions asking for software recommendations are not allowed here]

Comment: this is correct, i have to extend the exporter and then connect him to a new dashboard :) 

Exporter extension would be done in golang, but i would like to know what i need to export and if there are some dashboards that are already preconfigured with that :)

Maybe some of them needs paths, names, size, i have found so-far two "tree" plugins which i am planning to use now.

https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/equansdatahub-tree-panel/
https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/marcusolsson-treemap-panel/ 

But these i have found on my own, and was curious what other use :)